# Maven/ TestNg can't find allure @step annotation

Tags: maven, annotations, allure

Having a problem to implement allure @Step annotation into my maven project (tetsng, java).

(Updated) Sharing pom file:

```
eproject xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>src</groupId>
<artifactId>AutomationTestSuit</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <version>6.14.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>



<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src\main\resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src\test\resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <file>${project.basedir}/suites/smoke.xml</file>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment.properties>/environment.properties</environment.properties>
                </systemPropertyVariables>

                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.1/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>e
```

I'm trying to add Step annotation to the page class but it gets the failure:

```
package com.pages.login_page;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;


public class LoginPageElements {

private WebDriver driver;


@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "test")
private WebElement logonID;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "test")
private WebElement logonPassword;

@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "test")
private WebElement logonSubmit;


public LoginPageElements(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}

@Step("login step") //step is underlined on this place with can't resolve symbol Step error

public void Login_as(String sUsername, String sPassword) {
        logonID.sendKeys(sUsername);
        logonPassword.sendKeys(sPassword);
        logonSubmit.click();
}
```

[@Step error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xQz6.png)

the same problem I'm having with @Attachments while implementing it inside of MytestListener class:

[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSFz6.png)

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using out dated version of Allure. Here is correct import

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

With Allure 2 you do not need to configure Listener, but you need to configure AspectJ instead. Here you can find example for Maven + TestNG: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_testng

Comment: Updated to 2.6.0 and added the aspectj dependency with 1.9.1 version, the compilation works well. The report is generated but with any results. step annotations still doesn't work.

Comment: @Y_Sh can you share pom with changes?

Comment: @Y_Sh and which JDK is installed on the system?

Comment: the JDK is 1.8. Updated the pom.xml, please take a look

Comment: looks fine now, how do you generate report?

Comment: with the below command "allure serve target/allure-results". The report page is opened but has no data: Allure report unknown, 0 test cases, no Suits etc

Comment: do you have `target/allure-results` created after test execution? afaik, in Java adapters by default `allure-results` generated in project root

Comment: to change where `allure-results` are stored create `src/test/resources/allure.properties` with one line `allure.results.directory=target/allure-results`

Comment: yes, after the test run it generates the target/allure-results. I just updated allure.properties with the only one line and the report finally works!

Comment: BUT @Step annotation didn't come up to the pages classes.

Comment: Great! One step closer. If `@Steps` and/or `@Attachmetns` are missing from the report, then it usually means that there's a problem with AspectJ or JDK. Allure supports only JDK up to 1.8. From which package `@Step` is imported from?

Comment: they aren't missing from the report. Its actually unable to implement this annotation   through the class. LoginPageElements from the example. ( src/main/pages)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what the problem is. You can not import `@Step`, or it is not displayed in report, or... what does "unable to implement" mean?

Comment: Added the screenshot Step error example - that's how it looks when I'm adding the Step annotation above the method inside of the page class.

Comment: can you add these imports to class?
`import io.qameta.allure.Attachment;
import io.qameta.allure.Step;`

Comment: Did that but there is "can't resolve symbol io"  and both imports are grayed out,

Comment: for some reason IDE can not see dependencies set in Maven pom.xml

Comment: @Y_Sh which IDE is that? I can seen on a screenshot it offers an option to add Maven dependency. Try adding allure-testng using that IDE dialog

Comment: 2018.1.2 Community Edition. No result by searching allure-testng on that dialog. It seems like the dependency doesn't exist.

Comment: in IDEA you also need to have "Maven Integration" plugin installed in to be able to manage dependencies through pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

THE PROBLEM was with the idea community version. It appears that it doesn't support aspectj plugin. If someone will struggle with same issue please tale a look:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html

Answer (score 0):

I my case the problem was in `<scope>test</scope>`.
I removed it from dependancy:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
    <version>LAST_VERSION</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and @Step annotation starts to be recognized.